# Problem select specific column name using sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I found problem when trying to retrieve specific name column that using syntax/statement/command using sql.

Example I have table 'dcparam' with name some column 'SELECT', 'INSERT', 'UPDATE' in database sqlserver.
Then I trying to select using query:

```
SELECT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE FROM dcparam
```

Well it could be solve using "*" in select, but then how if i wish only specific column.

Regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add square brackets around the column name.

```
SELECT [SELECT], [INSERT], [UPDATE] FROM dcparam
```

It's probably best to reconsider your column names in the long run however...

Comment: +1: Agreed. And to re-iterate the posters comment for additional emphasis, you really must look to remove the use of reserved keywords as column names.